# How can I replace this JQuery Ajax call with JavaScript's builtin functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http-post

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript ajax request without framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907781/javascript-ajax-request-without-framework)

How can I make the JQuery Ajax call below without using JQuery or any other library but a by only using JavaScript built-in functions?

```
var input = '{
    "age":100,
    "name":"foo",
    "messages":["msg 1","msg 2","msg 3"],
    "favoriteColor" : "blue",
    "petName" : "Godzilla",
    "IQ" : "QuiteLow"
}';
var endpointAddress = "http://your.server.com/app/service.svc";
var url = endpointAddress + "/FindPerson";
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: input,
    success: function(result) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(result));
    }
});
```

Comment: I really do have to ask ... Why?

Comment: MDN has a wonderful write-up on [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) and what jQuery and other libraries do in the background for you.

Comment: What have you tried? Even **Google** finds the answer without anyone else having to *copy/paste* it for you.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery does a good job normalizing all the little quirks and nuonces between browsers for ajax calls.

I'd suggest finding a stand-alone ajax library that can do the same thing but without all the extra overhead jQuery brings with it. Here are a few:

- [Reqwest](https://github.com/ded/Reqwest)
- [Fermata](https://github.com/natevw/fermata)
- [Ajax](https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/ajax) (inspired by jquery/zepto)
- [Micro Ajax](http://code.google.com/p/microajax/)

Comment: [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) seems also to be promising nowadays

Answer (score 2):

Try this [Example](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first)

**First You have to create object of `window.XMLHttpRequest` or ActiveXObject (for IE)**

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
```

**Then You can send the request**

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

**At last You can Get the responce**

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The code below does everything that your jQuery version does:

- POST request with JSON as postdata
- Sets the JSON Content-type header
- Alerts the stringified response

Code:

```
  var httpRequest;

  function makeRequest(url, input) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
      httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
      try {
        httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      } 
      catch (e) {
        try {
          httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } 
        catch (e) {}
      }
    }

    if (!httpRequest) {
      alert('Giving up :( Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance');
      return false;
    }
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
          if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(httpRequest.responseText));
          }
        }
    };

    httpRequest.open('POST', url);
    httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    httpRequest.send(input);
  }

var input = '{
    "age":100,
    "name":"foo",
    "messages":["msg 1","msg 2","msg 3"],
    "favoriteColor" : "blue",
    "petName" : "Godzilla",
    "IQ" : "QuiteLow"
}';
var endpointAddress = "http://your.server.com/app/service.svc";
var url = endpointAddress + "/FindPerson";
makeRequest(url, input);
```

Taken partly from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started).

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at **Google**'s first answer [over here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_create.asp).