# Javascript game info to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

So after the player loses I want their score to be updated into the database using PHP.
I have a separate javascript class that actually runs the entire game but it uses setInterval to check the index.php function to check if the player lost; if they do they I want it to update the database. The update works but its not taking the score and is just replacing whatever highscore they had with 0.. obviously not what I want. I know people are going to recommend AJAX but my professor only wants PHP and Javascript so I'm getting really confused here... heres the function inside the index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function checkFinished(){
                if(end()){
                    <?php
                        if(isset($_SESSION["id"])){
                            $id = $_SESSION["id"];

                            $userName = $id["name"];
                            $update = "UPDATE bloodred SET score='?>score<?php' WHERE name='$userName'";
                            $update = $dbh->prepare($update);
                            $update->execute();
                        }
                    ?>
                    gameover = false;
                }
            }
</script>
```

as you can see im trying to grab the javascript variable score by doing this in the $update variable

```
score='?>score<?php'
```

does anyone know any quick short cuts to do this? thanks !

Comment: I think you're confused about how PHP interacts with javascript. The php you have set there will run on page load. The javascript that runs around it doesn't run the php again. Also AJAX is a part of javascript, so if your professor only wants PHP and javascript you should be able to use ajax too.

Comment: @AdamMerrifield The thing is he hasn't taught us AJAX, yet I need to update the high scores from the game. How would this be done with AJAX?

Comment: All you really need to do is make a request to another page with the score in it. So what you could really just do is in the checkFinished if `end()` `window.location = '/updatescore.php?score='+getScore();` then in `updatescore.php` do your php stuff. The page will reload after the game is over but it will send the request without ajax. Alternatively you can do this in an iFrame on the page so that you don't have the user leave the page

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is client side, and PHP is server side. When you remove the PHP from your javascript, you end up with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function checkFinished(){
                if(end()){
                    score
                    gameover = false;
                }
            }
</script>
```

If you would like to update the database with the content of a JavaScript variable, you will need to make a new request to the server. This can be a redirect, AJAX, socket, etc. But putting PHP inside of your javascript expecting it to execute like this just doesn't work.

Just a side note, this will work the other way around since PHP is executed first. This does not help your question, but might help clarify why your code isn't working:

This will work:

```
<script>
alert("<?php echo $variable; ?>");
</script>
```

Comment: How would I use a GET or POST method without actually asking for anything? I'm not using a form it's a canvas based game and I only need to update after the game is finished. Is there any way I could use the POST method in the way I am speaking of?

Comment: Yes, see this question for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907781/javascript-ajax-request-without-framework

Comment: @ConnorPrice you would call an event in JavaScript, for example (GameCompleted, ScoreChanged) and POST via AJAX (JavaScript) to the SERVER (PHP).

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing everything you all said to me I was able to think of a simple solution:
Heres the new javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkFinished(){
        if(end()){
            document.getElementById("setScore").value = score;
            gameover = false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

added a simple form:

```
<form name="highscore" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
            <input id="setScore" name="setScore" value="" type="submit" />
        </form>
```

then some php

```
<?
        if(isset($_POST)){
            if(isset($_SESSION["id"])){
                $id = $_SESSION["id"];

                $score = $_POST["setScore"];
                $userName = $id["name"];
                $update = "UPDATE bloodred SET score='$score' WHERE name='$userName'";
                $update = $dbh->prepare($update);
                $update->execute();
            }
        }
?>
```

Thought id post this in case anyone else needed it. Thanks again guys for your help!

Answer (score 0):

First of all: AJAX is Javascript.

Second: PHP is a Server-Side language. Javascript a Client-Side. So what you want mixing PHP code with JS code will never work. When JS execute, all PHP code was already evaluated and executed by PHP compiler.

To solve your problem there are some methods,like:

- You could use HTML5 WebSocket, but this is kind of AJAX and the user must have a updated, newer, browser and you must implement de server side of PHP socket to listen the user gameover event (too much resources of the server).
- You could use AJAX (since AJAX is Javascript), is the fast, easy and recomended.
- You could redirect the user, when the game over, to another page (or the same, this is your logic) passing a querystring or a cookie with the new score, doing this the PHP code can take the updated and correct value of score and update the database.

Just remember that all forms listed above are insecure because run in client-side and so, any client (AKA user/player) can change the value of score for whatever he wants.

If you cannot use AJAX (again, AJAX is Javascript), if you cannot use WebSockets (Server limitation or HTML 5 limitation), you could load a PHP through a script tag or a iframe tag (but don't tell anybody that was me who told you do that haha)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var score = getCurrentScore(); //a simple method that returns the current user score to be stored in database
 function updateScore()
 {
    var s = document.createElement("script"); // create a tag script via JS
    s.scr = "updateScore.php?score=" + score + "&nocache=" + Math.floor((Math.random()*1024)+1); // determine that source of this script is the url of script that updates the score for current user, with the queryString score value. nocache querystring with random value between 1 and 1024 is just to guarantee that the script will be loaded every time  and not a cached version of a file will be acessed. For better results add a HTTP header "expire" in the updateScore.php with a small or negative value.
    s.type= "text/javascript"; // type of script (make sure that updateScore.php response a content-type text/javascript e a valid or empty javascript code
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s); //append the tag script at the end of tag head of the current page  
 }

 // call updateScore() method when user gameover!
</script>
```

When you call the method **updateScore** it will produce something like:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="updateScore.php?score=1000&nocache=123"></script>`

This is similar a AJAX request, or a direct request or direct access to the file. Where **score=1000** represents a score with value 1000 and **nocache=123**  is a random value just to guarantee the fresh load of file. (calling method again, nocache value /probably/ will change to something different than 123...)

Comment: this isn't true with server side JavaScript but in the OPs question this is true.

Comment: using node.js and any of the following [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=server+side+javascript&oq=server+side+ja&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.4172j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8) you can run JavaScript on the server and at that time it will run fine with PHP...however it won't continue to update the server side variables without AJAX post.

Comment: My response was in relation to the context of the question. In case he does not need the SSJS (Server-side JavaScript) because the server is already taken by PHP, it would need something with CSJS (Client-side JavaScript) communicating with PHP ... My answer conforms to the context of the question!

Answer (score 0):

Without using ajax you can create an iframe and post to it using a form on the page with the target attribute.

javascript

```
function checkFinished(){
    if(end()){
        var iframe = document.getElementById('updateScore'),
            form = document.createElement('form'),
            input = document.createElement('input');
        if(!iframe){
            iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
            iframe.name = 'updateScore';
            iframe.id = 'updateScore';
        }

        input.name = 'score';
        input.value = getGameScore();

        form.action = '/updatescore.php';
        form.method = 'post';
        form.target = 'updateScore';
        form.appendChild(input);

        form.submit();
        form.remove();

        gameover = false;
    }
}
```

updatescore.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_SESSION['id']) && isset($_POST['score'])){
        $id = $_SESSION["id"];
        $score = $dbh->real_escape_string($_POST['score']);

        $userName = $id["name"];
        $update = "UPDATE bloodred SET score='$score' WHERE name='$userName'";
        $update = $dbh->prepare($update);
        $update->execute();
    }
?>
```