# How to send data from an Electron.js app to a remote server/db

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

As the title states, I'm having trouble finding a way to send data from an electron.js app to a remote db/server.

I can use mysql to connect directly with a database but it doesn't strike me as a secure thing to do. I would like to send the data, probably a json string, to a php or js file on a server and handle the validation and database access there.

I'm very new to working with node.js and electron.js but I'm really excited over the possibilities of it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got a working web server?

I'd recommend [express](https://expressjs.com/) - it's fairly simple to get started. You could define a route that you could post your data to, and then that would in turn add it to the database.

Comment: I'd read something on Express but I guess it wasn't a good article... I'll explore this option too.

Comment: You can use express generator (https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html) to create a boilerplate application. Inside a file `routes/index.js` you can add a new route to handle the data you've uploaded. Have a search for "handling post requests in express" and you should find some good articles. If you have more questions then comment here and I can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a standard AJAX request from the browserWindow of your Electron app. Please refer to this question:

[javascript ajax request without framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907781/javascript-ajax-request-without-framework)